# how to query the memory layout of pandas.dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to to query the memory layout of a pandas.dataframe. More explicitly, given a dataframe df (say, of the type np.float32), I would like to known if it is column-contiguous or row-contiguous.

Answer (score 1):

you can examine the `flags` attribute of the underlying numpy array. The underlying numpy array can be accessed through the `pd.DataFrame.values`

example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(12).reshape(4,3), columns=list('abc'))
df.values.flags
#outputs:
C_CONTIGUOUS : True
F_CONTIGUOUS : False
OWNDATA : False
WRITEABLE : True
ALIGNED : True
WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

As you can see from the output, in this case the data is row-contiguous (`C_CONTINUOUS`). `F_CONTINUOUS` signifies that the data is column-contiguous

Comment: Why do they have `C_CONTINUOUS` for row-contiguity and not for column-contiguity? That's so unintuitive. What does `C` and `F` stand for?

Comment: C and F stand for the programming languages C and Fortran. It's what they use for memory layout of multidimensional arrays.

Comment: It looks like `df.values` is generated on the fly, and isn't really the underlying numpy data. (If you have a mixed type dataframe, `df.values` will have `dtype=object`.) The real data seems to be in the tuple `df._mgr.blocks`. So you can examine `block.values.flags` for each block in there.

Comment: In addition to the above comment, `.values` is now deprecated, because of exactly this confusion.